# Read password from variable when executing a command

Tags: linux, mount, kde, cifs, smb

I have a network share I mount on a Linux-computer using the following command:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/path/to/credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0700 //192.168.6.9/myshare /where/to/mount`

I open KDE Konsole, run this command, enter my password and the share is mounted successfully. Everything works just fine. So I thought a graphical prompt for my password would be nice. A bit of googling and I ended up with the following command:

`MY_PASSWORD=$(kdialog --password "Give me your password")`

The question is, how can I "feed" this password in `$MY_PASSWORD` to the `sudo mount ...`-command? In other words, how can I avoid having to type the password in Konsole after running `sudo mount ...` and instead automatically read it from said variable?

Comment: Have you read https://askubuntu.com/a/1269207? Maybe it's what you need.

Comment: `man sudo` is a good starting point. In particular the options `-A` (`--askpass`) and `-S` (`--stdin`) may be of interest